# XMPP Bosh vs SignalR

Tags: xmpp, signalr

Does XMPP has more advantaces agains SignalR? They both using http long polling mechanism and I can not decide shall I use XMPP for my chat aplication or shall I use SignalR and keep everything ion my IIS server?

Answer (score 4):

SignalR uses several transports see the explanation here [How SignalR works internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807066/how-signalr-works-internally). Advantages of XMPP are the fact that greater number of other clients that just work out of the box (gchat, pidgin etc). But you could use both for your application if you wanted.

Comment: Do you want say that XMPP for chat application doesn't have any performance advantages?

Comment: I don't know of the performance advantages/disadvantages of XMPP over SignalR

Comment: We have tried 'openfire' XMPP, *all we wanted was a simple chat for our web app*, was a long process in setting up, configuring, etc, and we end up with an unstable chat server (im not sure if the fault is with openfire or our settings) we have given up on openfire. and now moving on to a simple 'signalR' app.

Advantage i see in signalR, its NOT a black box, you have control over how it works, cleaner integration with ASP.NET.

Comment: openfire is not as robust an implementation as ejabberd

Answer (score 1):

SignalR has a pile of ways for real time communication. WebSocket!! have you not heared about it? SignalR only use long pooling when nothing else is availabe on your old computer.

Comment: I hope you appreciate this is a comment not an answer (I get the fact that you can't post comments yet due to reputation).

Comment: Actually signalr has one real time transportation (websockets) and that is only available if the server has win8/2012server with IIS8 and .net 4.5. Then if the server has it you will get websockets if the client supports it. SignalR will gracefully fallback to other techniques such as forever frame (only IE) SSE (all but IE) and then longpolling.