# signalR api chatting android,ios, windows phone

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xmpp, signalr

Already i built chatting application in(Android, iOS & windows phone) & established in asp.net WebAPI, Now performance is very poor.

After googling i found, XMPP is the best & free(I am planning to use free open source tool, don't suggest paid lib)

Instead of XMPP, why we can't try with signalR?

Suggest me, which one should I go & start establishing the API.

I know compared to SignalR, XMPP have lot of features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMPP Bosh vs SignalR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616917/xmpp-bosh-vs-signalr)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it also with SignalR, or even as a combination of XMPP and SignalR.

XMPP is a complete presence and messaging protocol with lots of features and many available extensions (also non IM features). Its in production for over a decade now. It gives you all you need to build a IM/Chat app for free. So why to reinvent the wheel and rebuild all the existing functionality on your own with SignalR when you can just install an existing XMPP server, get a client XMPP library and start coding your chat application.