# Signalr transport channel for better performance

Tags: signalr

I am using the SignalR silverlight client and my hubs are hosted in the windows services. Hubs talk to the compact database to return the data.
What i have noticed is, the time taken to return the data is alarmingly high even though the volume of data returned is not significant and also since the hubs server is local, do not see any network latency issues as well.
I want to know, what are the performance improvements/configurations that can be done at the SignalR hub level in order to improve the performance?
eg:

1. Is there any standard Transport channel that I should use depending on the client type?
2. Are there any configuration parameters that i should set?

Thanks,
Alpee

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, SignalR uses fallback protocols so it would depend on the capabilities of your server and client.

You might want to take a look to this for [further abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807066/how-signalr-works-internally/7874352#7874352)

Moreover, there are some performance recommendations (only related to IIS and SignalR together) in the [main project wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance)

I would recommend you to use Performance Counters  (check "Generating Client Load with crank" section) to better diagnose where is your performance issue.

Hope that helps,

Cheers