# Push notification from an ASP.Net server

Tags: asp.net, push-notification

I have a web service that performs some operations. When an event occurs I will like to notify the clients. The problem that I have is that I am able to connect from the client to the server but not the other way around because clients happen to be behind a NAT (router). Currently I am making a request every minute to check for notifications. It would be nice if I can have a technique where I could notify the clients faster without having to make so many unnecessary request.

Note:
The client is a c# console application and the server is a asp.net website.

(note if an event happens on the server I will like to notify all clients)

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN. Finally, ASMX has no capability to notify.

Comment: Read up on "long polling". In essence: You have a poll request running, which waits on the server until either a timeout (e.g. 30 secs) or an event. Then immediately another poll is started.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at Microsoft's own library for this. [SignalR](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/) it abstracts out the real time data channel between the server and the client and uses the most efficient transport protocol out of 4 possible technologies (including and not limited to "long polling")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SignalR. This is Microsoft's new library for abstracting out real time server-client connections and if your setup allows it, it supports the new WebSockets protocol.

[Taken from asp.net website. The Client Code](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#establishconnection)

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");
stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>("UpdateStockPrice", 
    stock => Console.WriteLine("Stock update for {0} new price {1}", stock.Symbol, stock.Price));
await hubConnection.Start();
```

Comment: SignalR is great but you will need to consider backward compatibility with older browsers that do not support WebSockets.

Comment: @GregDzezinski The nice people at Microsoft did that already. [I will let another SOer explain...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7874352/1808494)

Comment: @GregDzezinski also the OP stated that the client is C# and hence not a browser.

Comment: Thanks @Aron.  Misplaced comment on my part.  I would like to add that SignalR itself is advertised as not support or tested in older browser versions.