# Generate the postback at proper time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I've a small web app which displays time in different time zones. Time calculation seems to be correct. I use the `timer` control to generate postback.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="60000" OnTick="Refresh_Time">
</asp:Timer>
```

Question:

The problem is the page refresh is not synchronized with the server clock. For example, if I've started the app at `9.55.30 AM` , the next postback is at `9.56.30 AM` So, right now, I've to watch the server clock and start the app at the when it is 0 seconds. Something like `9.57.00 AM`. Obviously, it is never 100% accurate.

Ideally, what I'm looking for is, no matter when I run the app `9.55.15 AM` or `9.55.45 AM`, the next postback should happen at `9.56.00 AM`. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

The code that solve the problem

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Timer1.Interval = 1000*(60 - DateTime.Now.Second);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page_load of your code behind you will need to calculate the actual interval to send to the client and set it there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered, in your Refresh_Time method, having the server do some sort of wait to post back until it reaches the minute?

Also, [I quickly found an existing question on 'push' notifications in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847764/push-notification-from-an-asp-net-server).  That could be a good option, too, because you can't assume the client can ever know what time it is on the server.