# How does SignalR work under the covers with built in transports?

Tags: websocket, signalr

First of, I read the information here http://signalr.net/

> You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it isn't, while your application code stays the same.
>
> SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect events, grouping connections, authorization.

---

And from answer here: [How SignalR works internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807066/how-signalr-works-internally)

> SignalR has a few built in transports:
>
> - WebSockets
> - Server Sent Events
> - Forever Frame
> - Long polling

I have a little problem with understanding the article (theoretically).

So how does SignalR work briefly for each build in transports? (easy English may help, since I'm complete new to SignalR and web socket)

1. WebSockets
2. Server Sent Events
3. Forever Frame
4. Long polling

Comment: "So how does SignalR work in real world with each build in transports?" - can you be more specific. This question is so vague that it is really hard to answer.

Comment: Ok, I meant that I want to know briefly how each build in transports work in SignalR. I updated the question.

Comment: Websockets - a websocket is being open (two way) and used for communication. Server sent events (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) the channel from the server to the client is opened and the client sends HTTP request and the server responds on the SSE channel, long polling - the client opens a request and waits for the server to response if the server does not have anything to send within 110 secs the client closes this request and opens a new one (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). These are not specific to SignalR so you can find a lot of stuff online.