# How to show real time counter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to process some records one by one , Need to show record number on .aspx page that currently we are processing nth record.

 Setting value of nth record in a label does not work as it will be reflecting only after response come back from server (it does not get refreshed for every record - looks like freezing )

Comment: solution to the freeze problem: use a new thread to calculate seconds

Comment: What about AJAX?

Comment: Ajax conflict with jquery and Bootstrap

Comment: @Emily , can you refer any example for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different techniques:

- Do server pulling via AJAX request by in some period. Good answered question on this topic - [Server polling with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583203/server-polling-with-javascript)
- Use `SignalR` to send changes back to client when there was changes on server. You can read about it more here: [How SignalR works internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807066/how-signalr-works-internally/7874352#7874352)

Choose one that is applicable in your case

Comment: What about Angular?

Comment: @Rahul With `Angular` you would implement server pooling. But it does not really matter how would you call `setInterval()` to call server for updates